# Copying files to a new directory

Tags: php, copy

This is what I have but I can't see what is wrong.

```
$site_name = $_SESSION['name'];

copy("../includes/teacher_webs_layout/index.php", "$site_name/index.php");
copy("../includes/teacher_webs_layout/teachers_web.php", "$site_name/teachers_web.php");
copy("../includes/teacher_webs_layout/teachers_web_sub.php", "$site_name/teachers_web_sub.php");
copy("../includes/teacher_webs_layout/.htaccess", "$site_name/.htaccess");
```

I'm trying to take them from the `teacher_webs_layout` folder and copy them to the `$site_name` folder which was recently created.

Comment: What is going wrong? Do you get errors? Do files fail to copy?  Most often, this is a result of the target directory not having write permissions for the user account trying to access it (the web server's user account, for example).

Comment: can you post the directory structure also? also, `echo $_SESSION['name'];`

Comment: Make sure you have error reporting turned on: `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` always in development...

Comment: I'd like to add that this approach is not recommended because if your web user may put arbitrary value in the `name` variable from your session, then your script will create a bunch of files in whatever place it was instructed to...